# Segue executes before previous code

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a bar button that I have created an `IBAction` for that will save a set of data to a server then return the user to the first of 3 data entry screens. In my current code, I am using a delay function to simulate the saving to server since I do not have the project ready to do that yet but I need to show how it will look when done.

Being very new to development in general, I am sure I am just missing a step here but I am at a loss to see what. This code executes exactly as expected until I introduced the `performSegueWithIdentifier` step. That is to say, when the Save button is tapped, the activity indicator begins animating, the code pauses for 4.0 seconds and then the activity indicator stops animating.  When I added the `performSegueWithIdentifier` step, and the button is tapped, the segue immediately executes.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
@IBAction func saveDTrans(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
// here is where data is saaved to server
    appIsWorking ()
    delay(4.0){
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnToDispenseScreenOne", sender: self)  //use this code to perform segue
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing the `delay` function? Not related to your problem, but is the "returnToDispenseScreenOne" segue an unwind segue?

Comment: Did you define the segue by ctrl-dragging from the bar button item?  If so, the segue is triggered automatically when you click the button, before the IBAction.

Comment: @rdelmar The `delay` function was a function I found here on SO by @matt. It works great and is very useful. As to your question, I don't know what an unwind segue is.

Comment: @pbasdf I did define the segue by cartel-dragging from the bar button item so that would explain my problem. How else can I set up the segue?

Comment: If you're not using an unwind, then you're probably doing something wrong. You should not go back to a previous controller with a "normal" segue, because those will not take you back, they will instantiate a new controller.

Comment: You make the segue by dragging from the view controller icon at the top of your controller, not the button, if you want to invoke it in code.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you. I had not used that method of creating a segue before. Is that the difference between a "normal" segue and an "unwind" segue? I am not familiar with those terms. If there is a reference where I can read about them, please point me to it. I am using the iBook by Apple "The Swift Programming Language" and i cannot even find the term segue when I search.

Comment: As per @rdelmar if you want to "go back" to an existing VC, you need to use an "unwind segue" - these need setting up a little differently. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12561735/3985749) for an explanation.

Comment: If you type "segues" into Xcode's documentation help, you will see several documents you can read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some code before segue execution then try

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Your Segue name") {
        // Your code that will run before segue execution
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will be using the `prepareForSegue` function in my app but not this particular need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delay, you can use an `NSTimer`:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: Selector("goToNextScreen:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

So, in your code:

```
@IBAction func saveDTrans(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
// here is where data is saaved to server
    appIsWorking ()

    // Run function goToNextScreen(_:) 4 seconds later
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: Selector("goToNextScreen:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func goToNextScreen(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnToDispenseScreenOne", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I really like the delay function that @Matt wrote since it is just a temporary function for me until I start connecting to the server where I will exchange information.  The activityIndicator will only be visible while the app is waiting to do the data exchange but I need the delay function during development so I can show my company what they will expect to see.